# JSP s:form, cannot resolve action

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

[image]Why? Cannot resolve action? Who can help me, thank you! 
  [image]

Comment: Have you tried to start your app? Post text not pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Servlet Path in action attribute:

```
<s:form action="pathToServlet/ServletClass">
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Looking at my update, is that a question of IDEA?

Comment: pathToServlet means the actual path to your servlet class.

Comment: Yes, it must have a realistic path, otherwise an error message will appear. Thank you!